# How to directly input datetime in mondodb?

Tags: mongodb, datetime, insert

I just wanna know how to input datetime in mongodb.

Like: db.collection.insert({username : "name", password : "somepass", createdat: datetimehere})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the shell

```
db.collection_name.insert({username : "name", password : "somepass", createdate: new Date() })
```

Mongo shell fully supports Javascript, so you can you any Javascript related methods.